# Create RecyclerView UI dynamically - Android

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I am working on an **e-commerce** App . Here I am working on **Products Filtering** . 
Here filters are dynamic, It means once filter page will display BRANDS and  PRICE then next time it can display BRANDS , PRICE , STYLES ..etc .
There may be many cases to filter products .

Application is receiving filters dynamically from Webservice .
So here I am creating filters dynamically using data received from the webservice . For this I am using RecyclerView to display dynamic filters 
.

Here is the code of RecyclerView where I am creating filters dynamically .

**onCreateViewHolder() :**

```
  @Override
public FilterViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LinearLayout topLayout = new LinearLayout(mContext);
    topLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    if (filterItems != null) {
        for (int filterItemsCount = 0; filterItemsCount < filterItems.size(); filterItemsCount++) {

            LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(mContext);
            ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            layoutParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);

            AFileterItem filterItem = filterItems.get(filterItemsCount);
            TextView textView = new TextView(mContext);
            textView.setText(filterItem.getFiletrLabel());
            ll.addView(textView);

            for (int i = 0; i < filterItem.getList().size(); i++) {
                VlauesItem item1 = filterItem.getList().get(i);
                CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(mContext);
                cb.setId(i);
                cb.setText(item1.getValueItemLabel());

                cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, String.valueOf(isChecked), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                ll.addView(cb);
            }

            topLayout.addView(ll);
        }
    }else{
        topLayout.addView(null);
    }

    FilterViewHolder viewHolder = new FilterViewHolder(topLayout);
    return viewHolder;
}
```

> Now , the problem is :

When I create filters dynamically then RecyclerView creates same filter more than once .
    I want to know how should I manage above code so that I can eliminate this problem .

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand what ViewHolders are. ViewHolder of a concrete type has single layout. If it is possible consider creating different viewholder types, or one with predefined layout, which will be customized in onBind callback. What you see is happening, because RecyclerView reuses view, and calls onCreateViewHolder only to fill the screen with items, then they are reused.

Comment: ViewHolder of a concrete type has single layout : I have a single layout at top i.e LinearLayout .

Comment: If it is possible consider creating different viewholder types : I don't need to create different-2 ViewHolders here since I have a top Layout

Comment: or one with predefined layout : I can't take predefined layout since it is not the requirement .

Comment: What you see is happening, because RecyclerView reuses view, and calls onCreateViewHolder only to fill the screen with items, then they are reused : I know this behaviour of RecyclerView , so I am confused here how should I manage code .

Comment: You expect each viewholder to have different layout and generate it dynamically. This is wrong. Please assume that you have one layout, whcih you don't change dynamically. Think that way and you will get the idea.